# Keep order in array, but change the values

Tags: php

Let´s say I´ve got an array like [3,2,8,4] (just an example, it can have more or less values).
I want the numbers to be in the same order but instead use numbers 1-4 (if there are 4 values as in this example), ie. [2,1,4,3].

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: writing code would be a good start. We're here to HELP, not do your job for you.

Comment: Every value in an array has an unique index. Use this index to change the value.

Comment: Try looking at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @MarcB well the thing is I don´t know where to start, that´s what I would like some HELP with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data =  [3,2,8,4];
$keys = array_keys($data);
array_multisort($data, SORT_ASC, $keys);
array_walk($keys, function(&$value) { ++$value; });
var_dump($keys);
```

Comment: Well done managing to pick the correct bones out of that question. They dont like to make it easy do they!

Answer (score -1):

,You could go with ArrayReplace.

```
<?php
$base = array(3 2, 8, 4);
$replacements = array(0 => 2, 1 => 1, 2 => 4, 3 => 3);

$store = array_replace($base, $replacements);


?>
```